# update table from a select

Tags: sql, oracle, ssms

I'm using ORACLE DATABASE 11g Express Edition and Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio 17.

I Have two tables

first table: CARS

```
Code | Brand_Model
01   | honda/HVR
02   | Volks/Golf
03   |  Fiat
```

second table: INFOS

```
Brand | Model
is empty for now
```

**here is the problem:**

I need to select the data from cars.brand_model and split. The data before the '/', i need to put in INFOS.Brand and the data after '/', i need to put in INFOS.Model
And, when there is no '/' (like de code 3 in table CARS'), i need to put the information 'no information' in INFOS.Model

**I did this select:**

```
select 
iif(CHARINDEX('/',c.brand_model,1) > 0, substring(c.brand_model,0,charindex('/',c.brand_model,1)),c.brand_model) as brand,

iif(CHARINDEX('/',c.brand_model,1) > 0, substring(c.brand_model,charindex('/',c.brand_model,1)+1,len(c.brand_model)),'NO INFORMATION') as model 
from CARS c;
```

This select shows the information exactly as i need, but is just a select.

```
Brand     Model
Honda     HVR
Volks     Golf
Fiat      No Information
```

I need to put these informations (these selects), inside the table Infos.

I put the brand, using the code bellow:

```
insert into infos (brand) select 
iif(CHARINDEX('/',c.brand_model,1) > 0, substring(c.brand_model,0,charindex('/',c.brand_model,1)),c.brand_model) 
from CARS c
```

and it is OK.
But now, I need to do an update in INFOS table, with the models. 
How can I do that?

Comment: I am really confused by your setup and code.  The code you have written does not work in Oracle.

Comment: Oracle 11g on SQL Server Management Studio ? what is it, a dblink / Linked server ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is working Oracle syntax, maybe you find it useful:

```
insert into infos (brand, model)
select case when instr(brand_model, '/') > 0 
            then substr(brand_model, 1, instr(brand_model, '/') - 1) 
            else brand_model
       end,
       case when instr(brand_model, '/') > 0 
            then substr(brand_model, instr(brand_model, '/') + 1) 
            else 'no information'
       end
  from cars
```

Answer (score 0):

Although the code you shared doesn't seems to be of Oracle but you can always use MERGE statement if you want to insert the data if not exists and UPdate the record if already exists.